# There are 5 balls in an urn: 3 blacks and 2 reds. We draw 2 balls from the urn. Let X = number of blacks balls drawn.

Tags: probability, random-variables

There are 5 balls in an urn: 3 blacks and 2 reds. We draw 2 balls from the urn.
Let X = number of blacks balls drawn.
(a) Find the distribution of X.
(b) Compute the expected value of X and the variance of X.
(c) Consider Y = number of red balls drawn. Argue that X + Y = 2 whatever the
outcome of the experiment is.
(d) Use the previous questions to compute E[Y ] with no sweat.
(e) Do we have V ar(X + Y ) = V ar(X) + V ar(Y ) ? Why not ?

I calculated E[X]=6/5, Var(X)=9/25, E[Y]=4/5, and Var(Y)=9/25

and can you explain what Var(X+Y) means in part "E"? Var(X) + Var(Y) just means find the sum of the two variances, but what does Var(X+Y) mean?

Comment: Hint:  For any two random variables $E[X_1+X_2]=E[X_1]+E[X_2]$.  For e), $X+Y$ is a random variable too.  It has a mean and a variance. (easy to compute in this case, but still.)

Comment: for the first part I know the linearity of expectation but E[X + Y] = E[X] + E[Y], this equals (6/5) + (6/5) = 2.4 not 2, I got the expectation of Y as (6/5)

Comment: $E(Y)\neq \frac{6}{5}$. It is true that $Var(Y)=Var(X)$, however.

Comment: thank you i saw the small algebra error i made, i got E[Y] = 0.8, now part D makes sense

Comment: for part e, does Var(X+Y) refer to a random variable where if X=number of lack balls drawn and Y=number of red balls drawn X+Y equals number of black and red balls drawn?

Comment: Yes.  And if you certainly draw 2 balls, what is the variance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and can you explain what Var(X+Y) means in part "E"? Var(X) + Var(Y) just means find the sum of the two variances, but what does Var(X+Y) mean?

It is just the Variance of the Sum.  Since the sum is the number of balls drawn, which is certainly $2$, what is the variance?

$$\mathsf {Var}(X+Y) = \mathsf {Var}(2) = \boxed{\,?\;}$$

---

Alternatively you can use the following:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf{Var}(X+Y) & = \mathsf E\big((X+Y)^2\big)-\big(\mathsf E(X+Y)\big)^2 & = \boxed{\;?\;}-\boxed{\;?\;} \\[1ex] & = \mathsf E(X^2)+2\mathsf E(XY)+\mathsf E(Y^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2-2\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(Y)-\mathsf E(Y)^2 \\[1ex] & = \mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2+\mathsf E(Y^2)-\mathsf E(Y)^2+2\mathsf E(XY)-2\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(Y) \\[1ex] & = \mathop{\mathsf{Var}(X)+\mathsf {Var}(Y)+2\underbrace{\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)}}_{\qquad\qquad\textsf{What does this last term mean?}}\end{align}$$

Comment: var(X+Y) is just zero because you're always going to be drawing 2 balls, it can never vary like X or Y can.

Comment: Exactly. @idknutting,